# How can I remove this logic from my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

I am trying to wrap my head around this problem. I know views shouldn't have that much logic in them. I have an app with users, posts and comments. Users have many posts and comments.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

Posts belong to users and have many comments.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

Comments belong to users and posts

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

In my post#show view I show comments under the post. I want to show the name of the user who made the comment. At the moment I have this in my view:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <b>Commenter:</b>
    <%= link_to  User.find(comment.userid).login, User.find(comment.userid) %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I should probably have that logic in my posts controller. But I am pretty confused. @post.comments returns an array(?) of comments belonging to the post. That means I can't have @commenter = @post.comments.userid. I am confused by the problem so I might not have explained it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact during the comments loop, you can use `comment.user` to get the data of the user since you have declared the `User` `has_many` `Comments` relationship.

Comment: One more suggestion, you could use `<%= render :partial => @post.comments %>` to loop through those comments one by one. In this case, you will have to extract the loop into another view file `_comment.html.erb`.

Comment: Yes, for cleaning up. My answer cleans your `User.find ...` in the view file, and my comment cleans your loop of `@post.comments.each`.

Answer (score 4):

To be more explicit on the first answer, you simply do this:

```
<%= link_to comment.user, comment.user %>
```

In your User model, override the to_s method like this so comment.user returns the string you want:

```
def to_s
  self.login
end
```

Finally, use eager loading to get all the data in one SQL call, instead of querying the DB separately for each comment.user.  In your Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :include => :user
```

And in the Post controller:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id], :include => :comments)
```